# enter visual basic formula in cell

Tags: excel, vba

Building an excel sheet in visual basic and I need to set a formula in a cell that says basically, if there is a value entered in column L, then put the date/time stamp in column K. The formula to do this in excel is:

```
=IF(L1<>"", IF(K1="", NOW(), K1), "")
```

And to set the column to allow iterative calculations. Is there any way to do this in visual basic?

Comment: Yes you can replicate such a formula in VB, but such a formula would be volatile, meaning `NOW()` would change on every single recalculation of your worksheet, opening and saving it. Is this what you really want? Otherwise I would say you should look into a `WorkSheet_Change` event, and intersect with `L` column.

Comment: I don't want the timestamp to be entered into K unless something is updated or entered into L.

Comment: Then the above comment will get you going =)

Comment: I didn't think of using the worksheet change event. That may just work. Thank youl